# Explanation of a script

Tags: linux, bash

**General description**
I don't understand the next script; the general idea is the script takes stdout and
writes down a file encoded(or shifted characters).

```
tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' <<EOF | bash -
  #!/ova/onfu
  ge '!-~' 'C-~!-B' < f-04-erfhygnqbf-rap.fu | onfu -
EOF
```

The first line seems to shifht characters based on two sets:

```
'A-Za-z'
```

and

```
'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

in some (random?) order. Then pipe it to bash.
Then it is defined a path

```
  #!/ova/onfu
```

but there isnt this path in the system nor interpreter, then whats the use?
next

```
  ge '!-~' 'C-~!-B' < f-04-erfhygnqbf-rap.fu | onfu -
```

ge ,I understand, is an option meaning greather than, but

```
'!-~' 'C-~!-B'
```

how can be greather than a character (using the utf8 code?, I mean their
hex values?)

this is taken of

```
f-04-erfhygnqbf-rap.fu
```

(is this a temporary file?). But then this is piped to onfu.

This scripts output a file with a whole mess of characters.

**Questions**
The general question: is what is this script doing?

As interesting points, I'd say :

- How does it work tr here?
- How does it work <<EOF?
- What is /ova/onfu?
- How does function the `ge` comparation?
- This script seems to reencode a stdout output, how can it be recovered?

Thanks.

Comment: To see what is happening, just delete `| bash -` and examine the output of `tr`.  It will greatly clarify things for  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tr` command is translating every letter to the letter 13 places ahead in the alphabet, wrapping around at `Z`. This is the [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) encoding.

The output of this is then piped to `bash`, so it will execute it as a shell script.

`<<EOF` indicates that the input to `tr` is a [here-doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). It passes all the lines until the `EOF` line as the input.

If you want to see the decoded script without executing it, get rid of `| bash` and it will be printed on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

`tr` is reading the content of the heredoc and translating it to produce:

```
#!/bin/bash
tr '!-~' 'P-~!-O' < s-04-resultados-enc.sh | bash -
```

(The text `#!/ova/onfu` is going through a ceaser cipher to become `#!/bin/bash`, `ge` becomes `tr`, etc.)

That string is then being executed by bash.